# VB.NET combobox persistence?

Tags: vb.net

I'm fairly new to VB.NET, and I've mainly been doing ASP programming up 'til now, and I have a pretty simple question.

I'm creating a program that will copy a selected file to a selected directory, and I want to store recent files/dirs so that they can be selected from a combo box. I was planning to just create a settings with "files" and "dirs", and just store the strings as `|` separated values (since that's an illegal file character).

Is there anything wrong with this approach, or are there any better methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is fine as it seems to be simply a local cache of recent directories.  You can persist the data in the application at the module level(create a module with a public object essentially is a global variable) but it goes away when the application is terminated.

[This article is using a similar approach to what you were thinking although the example is in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/RecentFileList.aspx)

Comment: That's basically what I was thinking. And since I do want persistence after the application is terminated, the file base approach is ideal. Nice link, too.